# Flutter tests keeps asking for packages already imported

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run a baseline test on Flutter before I get started developing tests and already it's failing asking for packages that are already included:

```
Compiler message:
 src/resources/news_api_provider_test.dart:17:5: Error: 'expect' is imported from both 'package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart' and 'package:test_api/src/frontend/expect.dart'. expect(sum, 4);
^^^^^^

src/resources/news_api_provider_test.dart:12:3: Error: 'test' is imported from both 'package:flutter_test/src/test_compat.dart' and 'package:test_api/test_api.dart'. test('FetchTopIds returns a list of ids', () {
^^^^^^
```

I have all these packages:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/src/test_compat.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/widget_tester.dart';
import 'package:test_api/test_api.dart';
import 'package:test_api/src/frontend/expect.dart':

void main() {
  test('FetchTopIds returns a list of ids', () {
    // Setup a test case
    final sum = 1 + 3;

    // expectation
    expect(sum, 4);
  });
}
```

What gives here? I don't see anything in the flutter.io documentation to clarify what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `import 'package:test/test.dart';` has been replaced with `import 'package:test_api/test_api.dart';`, but it has not made it to their documentation yet.

After replacing that and commenting out my `news_api_provider.dart` import like so:

```
// import 'package:news/src/resources/news_api_provider.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:test_api/test_api.dart';
import 'package:test_api/src/frontend/expect.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http/testing.dart';
```

I got the baseline test passing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using either one of

```
    import 'package:flutter_test/widget_tester.dart';
```

or

```
    import 'package:flutter_test/expect.dart';
```

And similarly try to use either one of

```
    import 'package:flutter_test/src/test_compat.dart';
```

or

```
    import 'package:flutter_test/src/test_api.dart';
```

Let's see if this fixes the compilation error.

Comment: @mahadav, I still get the same error message after just selecting one of each corresponding packages.

Comment: @Daniel I am sure you have gone through this, if not please take a look into this documentation and see if you can figure it out. 
https://pub.dev/packages/test

Comment: I was not looking at that documentation, I was using flutter.io, but according to what you provided, the package is: `import "package:test/test.dart";` which I initially had, but flutter said no, it had to be `import "package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart";`. So I went back to `import "package:test/test.dart";` and the error for `expect()` and `test()` disappeared, but I still get no test passing, this time the error saying that `import "package:test/test.dart"; Not Found`. If you look here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24384, this is my situation, but the solution did not work.

Comment: I guess at issue here is, what should I have in my `dev_dependencies: test: ^1.5.1`? or `flutter_test: sdk: flutter`?